# hibernateexception - could not instantiate resultclass

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting the following error during transformation of result:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate resultclass: com.javatpoint.mypackage.EmployeeDTO
    at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.hql.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultList(CustomLoader.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:150)
    at com.javatpoint.mypackage.StoreData.unionqry(StoreData.java:54)
    at com.javatpoint.mypackage.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:19)


public static void unionqry(){
    Session session = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
            .buildSessionFactory().openSession();

    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

    String sql = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM EMP1000 union Select firstName, lastName from Emp1000";
    //String sql = "SELECT a.id,b.emp_dept FROM test.emp1000 a inner join emp_dept b on a.id = b.id";
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    List result = query.addScalar("firstName").addScalar("lastName").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(EmployeeDTO.class)).list();
    Employee e = (Employee)result.get(0);
```

Tranformclass:

```
class EmployeeDTO{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public EmployeeDTO(){}

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your hibernate mapping file

Comment: I fixed the issue..The class needs to be declared public...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using annotation mapping instead of using xml mapping.

If that is the case than you should provide mapping information in your POJO class(EmployeeDTO)
Check these examples:
[example-1](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-hello-world-example-annotation/)             [example-2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm)  for further explanation.